# JBoss tracing JDBC on OpenShift

Tags: jboss, openshift

I have an OpenShift Deployment with 14 replicas in production environment.
I need to activate a trace **on a single pod/replica** and I have found the following jboss-cli.sh commands to do it

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=MySQLPool/:write-attribute(name=spy,value=true)      
/subsystem=logging/logger=jboss.jdbc.spy/:add(level=TRACE)
/subsystem=jca/cached-connection-manager=cached-connection-manager/:write-attribute(name=error,value=true)
```

but when i enter those commands ***reload*** is required.

If I do a

```
:reload
```

the pod I am on restarts and the given configuration is lost.

Is there an altervative way to activate ***pool tracing*** ?

thanx a lot in advance!

Comment: You need to change your image configuration and redeploy it. deployments are 'immutable' so changing the configuration should be done before running the deployments.

Comment: thanx for the answer
I forgot to say that I need to do it on a single pod...
I add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: it wai in OpenShift Heath Check configuration

Liveness probe period was too small, so it caused killing while jboss reloading was in progress.

Rising the value gives Jboss time for reloading without killing the Pod.